# Why I have White-label Error Page in my Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have this error when I'm run my spring-MVC code:

White-label Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Oct 13 21:47:24 EEST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

**This is my pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.mahmoud</groupId>
        <artifactId>FirstSpring</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>FirstSpring</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.9</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.53</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

**Here is the controller of my application extended from HttpServlet**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/login")

public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

**The HTML code**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>HTML Tutorial</title>
<body>
<h1>This is a jsp</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
   <display-name>Students DB</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```